# How to update current entities using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a gmail service that returns me the names and phonenumbers of my contacts. to store these information into my database I have created two simple poco classes

so what I want to do is : 1-to prevent duplicates 
2- I may update contacts information on the gmail so next time I call the below function I would like to update the contacts. how do I do this?

```
public class CONTACTS_INFO
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CI_ROWID { get; set; }

    public int CI_CONTACT_REFNO { get; set; }

    public string CI_PHONE_NUMBERS { get; set; }
}

public class GMAIL_CONTACTS
    {
        public GMAIL_CONTACTS()
        {
            CONTACTS_INFO = new List<CONTACTS_INFO>();
        }
        [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int GC_ROWID { get; set; }

        public string GC_CONTACT_NAME { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CI_CONTACT_REFNO")]
        public List<CONTACTS_INFO> CONTACTS_INFO { get; set; }
    }
```

following is my method

```
using (var context = new MPContext())
            {

                foreach (var contact in cr.GetContacts().Entries)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.Name.FullName)) continue;
                    var gContacts = new GMAIL_CONTACTS { GC_CONTACT_NAME = contact.Name.FullName };

                    foreach (var phonenumber in contact.Phonenumbers)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(phonenumber.Label)) continue;
                        gContacts.CONTACTS_INFO.Add(new CONTACTS_INFO { CI_PHONE_NUMBERS = phonenumber.Value + phonenumber.Label });
                    }
                   //Here I would like to do two things
                   //1-Check if I have this contact in database so I wont save it
                   //2-I may change information on the gmail so I would like to update my contacts 
                        context.GMAIL_CONTACTS.Add(gContacts);                       
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Please, though off-topic, adhere to C# naming conventions. Don't let these database names trickle down to your C# code. It makes the code unnecessarily hard to read. Also, use plural names for collections only, not for type names and scalar property names. On-topic: your question is too broad. Where *exactly* do you have problems in doing "this"? And what is "this"? Which duplicates do you want to prevent and do you have proper unique indexes as a final safeguard?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement an upsert with EF you need

1. search for an entity with the same primary key,
2. If you don't find the entity you create and add a new one (without saving),
3. write the entity properties and
4. SaveChanges

There are variants but using EF you need an access to the database to know if you need to insert or modify the entity.